# How to assign "default" values in class?

Tags: python

Let's assume the user input is correct, why does the input not match?
How can I set the value of `playClass` in the constructor?

```
class player():
    playClass = None
    items = []
    level = 1

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        x = input('Welcome! Select a class: W for warrior, M for Magician, B for Bowmaster')

        match x.lower:
            case 'w':
                self.playClass = 'Warrior'
            case 'm':
                self.playClass = 'Magician'
            case 'b':
                self.playClass = 'Bowmaster'
    
    def player_add_item(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
    
    def player_add_level(self):
        self.level += 1

    def player_get_class(self):
        return self.playClass

p = player()
print(p.playClass)
```

Comment: `x.lower()`, not `x.lower`.  It's a method, not a property.

Comment: Yep, thank you. New to python, have to get used to it :)

Comment: Since you're using type annotations, you can use `mypy` and it ought to be able to catch errors like that for you (e.g. it'll tell you that you're trying to `match` a function against strings, which will never work).

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign to them in `__init__`; as written, they're all *class* attributes (shared between all instances, and visible on the class itself), not instance attributes (unique to each instance).

```
class player():

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        x = input('Welcome! Select a class: W for warrior, M for Magician, B for Bowmaster')
        self.playClass = None
        self.items = []
        self.level = 1

        match x.lower:
            case 'w':
                self.playClass = 'Warrior'
            case 'm':
                self.playClass = 'Magician'
            case 'b':
                self.playClass = 'Bowmaster'
```